# How to use scope variable from http.get outside the success function in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know how can I use the scope.hello value outside the success function in my controller. Here is where its getting populated in my controller file:

```
$http.get(BaseUrl().url + 'jury/UpcomingEvents?someID=' + someID)
     .success(function (response) {
         $scope.UpcomingEvents = response;
         $scope.hello= $scope.UpcomingEvents[0].EventID;
     });
```

I want to be able to use the value of $scope.hello in another array outside the http.get function like so:

```
var Count=3;
$scope.Total= $scope.hello + Count
```

so that I can output $scope.Total in my html file as following.

```
{{Total}}
```

Right now, $scope.hello remains undefined as its not retaining the value from the success function as I understand, it is an asynchronous function.

Is there a way to use this value in other places in my controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cant you just do this,

```
var count = 3;
$http.get(BaseUrl().url + 'jury/UpcomingEvents?someID=' + someID)
     .success(function (response) {
         $scope.UpcomingEvents = response;
         $scope.hello= $scope.UpcomingEvents[0].EventID;
         $scope.Total= $scope.hello + Count
});
```

Comment: I can do that, but I actually would be editing the entire array Upcoming Events and then have to present a new array in the html. Should I do that all inside the success function? Is that a recommended method and would that work? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: you can create a function to do that and pass the value to that

Comment: Yes it did! I accepted your answer! As per your suggestion, I used the result inside the success function and that worked! Thanks!